# how to get the text of bootstrap alert message for testing with protractor

Tags: jasmine, protractor, karma-runner, karma-jasmine, karma-mocha

this is my spec

```
 it('should save edited majorObject', function () {
        var description = element(by.id('objectDescription'));
        description.clear();
        description.sendKeys('edited');
        var add = element(by.id('saveObject'));
        add.click().then(function () {
            expect(element(by.css('.alert-success')).isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
         expect(element(by.css('.alert-success')).toText()).toBe("Saved Successfully");

        })

    });
```

i used
`expect(element(by.css('.alert-success')).toText()).toBe("Saved Successfully");`

But it is showing undefined and is their any alternative way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You meant to use `getText()` instead of `toText()`:

```
expect(element(by.css('.alert-success')).getText()).toBe("Saved Successfully");
```

Comment: i tried your code, even though it is showing an error as this
`Expected x close Successfully Done  tobe successfully Done` it is getting some extra text along with it! But i want only that specific text

Comment: @SYEDRASHEED that's a separate problem now, which you can address by using, for instance, `toContain()` or `toMatch()`.